# Basis and dimension of a real vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help me to find out the basis and dimension of a vector space $$\{(x,mx)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$$ for some $m\in\mathbb R$, $m\neq0$, over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: $$(x,mx) = x(1,m)$$

Comment: Means it is one dimensional?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: There is one parameter, so *if* it is a vector space, it is one dimensional

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=\{(x,mx):x\in\mathbb R\}$ and $(x,mx), (y,my)\in V$ be non-zero vectors. Then if 
$$
c_1(x,mx) + c_2(y,my) = (0,0)
$$
for some $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb R$, we have $c_1x + c_2y = 0$ (the other equation is equivalent as it just differs by a factor of $m$). Write $y = -\frac{c_1}{c_2}x$, then it is clear that $(x,mx)$ and $(y,my)$ are linearly dependent. It follows that $\dim V<2$.

Now, $(1,m)\in V$ and clearly $c(1,m)=(0,0)$ implies that $c=0$. Hence $\dim V=1$ and in particular $\{(1,m)\}$ is a basis for $V$. For if $(x,mx)\in V$, then $x(1,m) = (x,mx)$.

Geometrically, you can think of $V$ as a line passing through the origin in $\mathbb R^2$ with slope $m$.